# How to do large number of arithmetic operations

Tags: reference-request, advice

I'm having trouble with doing long arithmetic operations. Generally if the equation involves addition, subtraction, division and multiplication and it's larger than 2-3 lines of A4 paper, I can be sure that I will make a mistake. I'm still in high-school and I rarely have to deal with so large equations. But now I'm learning a new type of problems - given two quadratic equations with parameter find values of the parameter such that the two equations have common root(s), and it's seems that every time I would have to solve such problem, I would be dealing with large equation.

Comment: Try to be concise and efficient in the steps you take.

Answer (score 2):

Several things you can do:
1) make your calculations more slowly, do not hurry
2) check or cross-check your calculations after every 3 steps or so
3) try not to make a mistake from step N to step N+1
4) practice by solving more problems

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Understood you wrong
Updated my answer

You can find all the roots of $f(x)$ so that $f(x)=0$ and then create a system of linear equations with $g(x)$

Let $x_1,x_2$ be the roots of $f(x)$

Now solve for $a$:

g($x_1$)=0

g($x_2$)=0

Let us use your example:

$f(x)=a*x^2-x+1$

$g(x)=2ax^2-x^2+6ax+1$

$f(x)=0$

This gives us the roots:

$x_1=\frac{1}{2a}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4a^2}-\frac{1}{a}}  $

$x_2=\frac{1}{2a}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4a^2}-\frac{1}{a}}  $

Now we plug it into $g(x)$

g($\frac{1}{2a}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4a^2}-\frac{1}{a}}$)=0

g($\frac{1}{2a}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4a^2}-\frac{1}{a}}$)=0

This is now a system of linear equations.
The only step to do, is to solve it.

Comment: Well the method presented in my textbook is completely different.
Let $f(x) = a*x^2 -x + 1 =$ and $g(x) = (2a-1)x^2 +6ax +1 =0$ are the given function.
First - Let $f(x) = 0$ when a = 0 (Make $f(x)$ linear and = 0) and $g(x) =0$ when a = 0 
Secod - Let $g(x) = 0$ and a = $1/2$ (Make $g(x)$ linear and = 0) and $f(x) =0$ when a = 1/2
Third - If they have common roots and those roots are $x_1$ and $x_2$ then $f(x_1) =  0$ and $f(x_2) = 0$, then $f(x_1)*f(x_2) = 0$ then I have to get $x_1+x_2$ and $x_1*x_2$ from Viet's formula from $g(x)$

Comment: My fault, I thought you were looking for the intercept of the two functions.

Comment: You can find all the roots of $f(x)$ so that $f(x)=0$ and then create a system of linear equations with $g(x)$

Let $x_1,x_2$ be the roots of $f(x)$


Now solve for $a$:


g($x_1$)=0

g($x_2$)=0

This is not harder and just as intuitive.

Comment: Do you mean solving $f(x) = 0$ and trying those roots on $g(x)$ ? Because I'm not sure if this will work. Also you can write squareroot like this: \sqrt{} Demo : $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Well this will be hard, since I don't know the value of the parameter, nor it's range.

Comment: @Planet_Earth I updated my answer